# Merge Field value is not being captured upon Web to Lead creation

Tags: visualforce, email-template, web2lead

I have a requirement where in I have to put a link in the email sent to Lead after the web to lead creation. I need to add the Id of freshly created Lead to the link inside the email body sent to that particular lead.

When I try using Lead auto response rule, data in merge fields are not displayed.
but, when I check it using  " Send test and Verify Merge fields" button I can see the data.

VF TEMPLATE:

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Invitation" recipientType="Lead" relatedToType="Lead">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >

Congratulations!
This is your new Visualforce Email Template.

{!relatedTo.Id}


</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

Am I missing something? As per my understanding, this should work.

PS: The same template if used in the workflow is working fine. I need to utilize the Assignment rules that's the reason I am not going with Workflow rule.

Any Help is appreciated ! thanks

Comment: Are you using the System Admin Profile?

Comment: yep !  @CarlosNaranjo .
The thing is , I need to send some  redirecting links inside this email. So I need Lead Id and Name to pass it in the URL . But , I am not getting the merge field values when I create a lead.

but when I use "Send test and Verify Merge fields" button its working fine.

Comment: are you using web-to-lead through API?

Comment: @SantanuBoral I hope its an API call as we see its a POST Method.

Comment: If this template is only used for Web-To-Lead, try using either the `Who.Id`, `What.Id` or `Lead.Id` and see if one of those doesn't solve your issue.

Comment: @crmprogdev
Throws "Unknown property 'core.email.template.EmailTemplateComponentController.Lead' 
" error  if I use Lead

Error: Unknown property 'core.email.template.EmailTemplateComponentController.Who'   for Who.Id

Error: Unknown property 'core.email.template.EmailTemplateComponentController.What'  for What.Id

This is working fine for another guy. It is strange how a std functionality is giving trouble

Comment: I was able to fix it by replacing relatedTo.Id with the recipient.Id  then it was giving the created lead record in the email.

As I know, recipient is the one who receives and related To is the object whose merge fields are being populated right?

Comment: RelatedTo is term used when there's a Polymorphic relationship which can be one of several objects including the record object, a contact, or a lead. It's not always limited to the record object. So yes, it's related to the appropriate merge field.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by replacing relatedTo.Id with the recipient.Id then it was giving the created lead record in the email. As I know, recipient is the one who receives and related To is the object whose merge fields are being populated right?